# Enabling properties with xs size in bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a web page that does the following: When the user gets the focus of an input tag, the page enables the input tag next to it. It works fine when the size of the window is large; but when the windos get smaller (simulating a phone screen), the page doesn't work properly (the next input tag doesn't get enabled)

I noticed that it happens when the next input tag to enable is in another line when the screen is bigger. Despite, the issue is when the screen is small. Also, It works fine in IE10; but in Chrome and Firefox it doesn't work.

The html code and JS is this: http://jsfiddle.net/c8fvrzab/

```
<section id="featuressection" class="cajas-formulario">
    <form>
       <fieldset>
          <legend>Features</legend>  
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label class="control-label" for="line1-1">line1-1</label>                    
              <input id="line1-1" name="line1-1" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control input-md mayusculas"  disabled="disabled"></input>
         </div>                  
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <label class="control-label" for="line1-2">line1-2</label>                         
             <input id="line1-2" name="line1-2" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control input-md"  disabled="disabled"></input>
         </div>                            
         <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xs-12 ">
             <label class="control-label" for="line2-1">line2-1</label>                           
             <input id="line2-1" name="line2-1" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control input-md mayusculas"  disabled="disabled"></input>
         </div>              
         <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label" for="line2-2">line2-2</label>                        
            <input id="line2-2" name="line2-2" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip"  class="form-control input-md"  disabled="disabled"></input>
         </div>                            
         <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label class="control-label" for="line2-3">line2-3</label>                        
            <input id="line2-3" name="line2-3" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control input-md"  disabled="disabled"></input>
         </div>                         
</section>
```

this is the js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setup();
});

function setup() {
    $("#line1-1").attr('disabled', false);
    $("section[id=featuressection] input").focus(enableNext);
}

function enableNext(event) {
    $(this).parentsUntil("fieldset").last().nextAll().first().find("input, select").attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Try resizing the window to see different behavior.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `col-xs-12` from `<div class="form-group col-md-8 col-xs-12 ">`. The issue appears because the next div takes all the space.

Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hzrc7bd1/) working fine.